# Usage of $\hat p$ and $p_0$ in confidence intervals/hypothesis testing

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

Cheers, I have a question about the usage of $\hat p$ and $p_0$ when talking about the confidence intervals of proportion problems.

My professor and my textbook both state that for Bernoulli trials (So $X_1, X_2, \cdots X_n$, $X_i \sim Bernoulli(p)$), with $n \geq 30$, then $$Z = \frac{\hat p - p_0}{\sqrt{\frac{\hat p (1- \hat p)}{n}}}$$, and $Z \sim N(0,1)$

However, I came across a [webpage](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat415/lesson/9/9.2), and some tutorials which instead of the above type, they used the following one: $$Z = \frac{\hat p - p_0}{\sqrt{\frac{ p_0 (1- p_0)}{n}}}$$

Why is that change there on the variance? Does it have to do with the sample size, or is it something I am omitting or understanding wrong? Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**: An answer is given in the note [here](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat415/lesson/9/9.3), but I would like a more intuitive explanation if possible =)

Comment: Some of these notations are used for making confidence intervals and some for testing hypotheses. I show examples of each in my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Confidence intervals.** Suppose you are making a 95% CI for unknown success probability $p,$ based on $n = 100$ Bernoulli trials. resulting in $x = 30$ successes.  Then $\hat p = x/n = 30/100 = 0.3.$

Then the standard error of $\hat p$ is
$SD(\hat p) = \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}.$ Also,
$Z = \frac{p-\hat p}{SD(\hat p)}$ would be approximately standard normal. However, you can't evaluate $SD(\hat p)$ because $p$ is unknown.

For large $n$ you could get a good estimate of
$SD(\hat p)$ of the form
$\widehat{SD}(\hat p) = 
\sqrt{ \frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n} }.$

From there you can make an *approximate* 95% CI for $p$
of the form
$$\hat p \pm 1.96\sqrt{ \frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n} }.$$

This is a Wald CI for $p$ based on the assumption that $n$ is large, and it is usually accurate enough for practical
use if $n > 500.$ For very small $n,$ this style of CI.
has very bad properties. For some values of $p$ the 'coverage
probability' can be far from 95% (more or less than 95%,
but most often lower).

*A better style of CI* (due to Agresti and Coull) uses $\tilde p = \frac{x+2}{n+4}$
and the formula
$$\tilde p \pm 1.96\sqrt{ \frac{\tilde p(1-\tilde p)}{n+4} }.$$

For $n = 100, x = 30,$ the two CIs are as follows (computed using R as a calculator).  Wald; $(0.21, 0.39);$  Agresti-Coull:
$(0.22,  0.40).$

```
n = 100;  x = 30
p.hat = x/n
CI.w = p.hat + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*sqrt(p.hat*(1-p.hat)/n)
CI.w
[1] 0.2101832 0.3898168

p.est = (x+2)/(n+4)
CI.ac = p.est + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*sqrt(p.est*(1-p.est)/(n+4))
CI.ac
[1]  0.2189891 0.3963955
```

There are many styles of CIs for binomial proportions,
some of them explained in the relevant [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) article.

**Test of hypotheses:** Now, suppose you want to use data $n = 100, x = 30$ to test $H_0: p = 0.35$ against $H_a: p \ne 0.35.$  According to $H_0$ you have $p_0 = 0.35.$
The estimate from data is $\hat p = x/n = 0.3.$

The test statistic for an approximate normal test is
$Z = \frac{p_0 - \hat p}{\sqrt{ \frac{p_0(1-p_0)}{n} }}.$
You reject $H_0$ at the 5% level of significance, if $|Z| \ge 1.96.$ Because $Z = 1.048,$ the null hypothesis is not rejected.

```
z = (.35 - .30)/sqrt(.35*(1-.35)/100);  z
[1] 1.048285
```

**Exact procedures in R.**  In R statistical software
you can test the hypothesis above and get a
95% CI, without using any normal approximations.

```
binom.test(30, 100, p=.35)

         Exact binomial test

data:  30 and 100
number of successes = 30, number of trials = 100,
 p-value = 0.3454
alternative hypothesis: 
 true probability of success is not equal to 0.35
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.2124064 0.3998147
sample estimates:
 probability of success 
                    0.3
```

The null hypothesis is not rejected because the P-value
$0.3454 > 0.05 = 5\%,$ and a 95% CI for $p$ is
$(0.212, 0.400).$

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question, let me clear a few things up.
I assume that $\hat{p}$ is the empirical estimator for the unknown parameter $p$, that is $\hat{p} = \frac{1}{n} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1} \{ X_i = 1 \}$.
The test statistic
$$
Z_n = \frac{\hat{p}_n - p}{\sqrt{ \frac{\hat{p}_n (1-\hat{p}_n)}{n}}}
$$
is **not** distributed as $Z_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ for $n \geq 30$.
The formally correct statement is that distribution of the test statistic $Z_n$ *approaches* a normal distribution as $n$ grows.
The formal statement is that $Z_n$ approaches $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ [in distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution).

When we construct confidence intervals, we often make the "asymptotic approximation" by *pretending* that $Z_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.
This is how we get $(1 - \alpha)$-confidence intervals of the form
$\hat{p}_n \pm \Phi^{-1}(1 - \alpha)\sqrt{ \frac{\hat{p}_n (1-\hat{p}_n)}{n}}$, where $\Phi^{-1}: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the quantile function of the normal distribution.
We can only prove the validity of these confidence intervals asymptotically as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
But, we often smudge things by saying that a finite sample size $n$ (say, 30) is close enough in practice.

---

Okay, to answer your question: your professor gave you $\sqrt{ \frac{\hat{p}_n (1-\hat{p}_n)}{n}}$ as an estimate for the variance. This is something that you can obtain from your data - it is a quantity that is known to you.
On the other hand, using $\sqrt{ \frac{p (1-p)}{n}}$ would be great, but it's impractical because you do not know the true parameter $p$ from your data.
So, the relevant test statistic to analyze is $\sqrt{ \frac{\hat{p}_n (1-\hat{p}_n)}{n}}$.

Both of these quantities would yield a test statistic $Z_n$ is asymptotically normal. But, again, only on of them is computable from your data.